# Manipulating unintended style change from theme

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I've applied the [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) theme to my project. I've noticed that it may have produced an unwanted rectangular area in my ListView. Snoop indicates that this unwanted area is part of an item named "Bd" (ListBoxChrome.)

[image]

[image]
In experimentation, I've applied the default ListView and ListViewItem styles to this ListView's parent:

Parent UserControl:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../DefaultWPFSyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
...
```

DefaultWPFStyles,xaml:

```
...
    <Style TargetType="ListView"/>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem"/>
...
```

With the intention of resetting those styles with no luck. I'm wondering if someone could suggest a way to address it. I'm currently researching how to look up and directly manipulate the ListBoxChrome object.

*Edit

I rolled back to prior build and see that ListBoxChrome has been there. I also edited a copy of ListView in Blend, hoping to get access to the chrome object, but it's not in the generated xaml ListView style.

That extra space is the size of the group header so I'm wondering if there is some offset being applied somewhere.

*Edit
The ListBoxChrome element is a Decorator an is part of the [aero theme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.listboxchrome(v=vs.85).aspx). Looks like it's not present in an empty list but is added when a ListView.View is declared.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce your issue, but I do have a few thoughts.

Given that `ListBoxChrome` comes from [PresentationFramework.Aero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.themes.listboxchrome.aspx) I suspect that it will only show up on systems that are using Aero (just a guess).

I think the biggest clue comes from your snoop screenshot. The name of the `ListBoxChrome` element is "Bd". If you [search the MDIX library for this](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/search?q=Bd) you will only find a couple references to it. However, there is only a couple instances where the "Bd" element is the direct parent of an unnamed ScrollViewer. The most likely candidate is the one in the [ListBox template](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ListBox.xaml) since ListView derives from ListBox. As a simple test, try setting the `BorderBrush`, `BorderThickness` properties since these are the ones that are being bound to the Border and see if that is really what is happening here.

Now I am not sure how it would be resolving to that style. It would require seeing more code around your other resource dictionaries (and possibly other styles that may be getting applied).

Comment: No success with changing those. Same results when I explicitly set the ListView BorderThickness, Padding and Margin all to 0. The border in the images above comes from a direct parent grid of the ListView.

Comment: ListBoxChrome is providing the ListView's background color. I could set it to transparent, supply the background color on the parent grid and set some negative top margin to the ListView to cover this up. I can tell that the ListView top and the ListBoxChrome top are not aligned (the actual issue) - still fiddling...